# How do I add other plots to a stacked plot?

Tags: pgfplots

If I have a `ybar stacked` axis type, how can I add another plot such as a `jump plot` on top?

The example below shows more or less what I need:

[image: mixed stacked bar plot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can switch off the stacking for a single plot by using `stack plots=false`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
colormap={whitered}{color(0cm)=(white); color(1cm)=(orange!75!red)}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    samples=10,
    ybar stacked,
    ymin=0,
    set layers
]
\addplot +[white, draw=black] {rnd};
\addplot +[gray!50, draw=black] {rnd};
\addplot [
    very thick, red!75!black,
    const plot,
    stack plots=false,
    on layer=axis foreground
] {rnd};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Answered in no time, thanks Jake!  Also answered question [tag:115152] for me.

Comment: @user1831847: Pleasure! However, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115152/how-to-mitigate-same-number-of-coordinates-error is still open, because this approach only works if the `const plot` has the same number of coordinates as the stacked plots (which is really a bug, I believe, because once we set `stack plots=false`, the number of coordinates shouldn't matter).

Comment: I agree with you that it should reset the number of coordinates as well.  Maybe `stack plots=reset`?